# How to make grep not interpret special characters in my search string?

Tags: bash, grep, escaping

When executing `./test.sh 12.34`, the grep should match `12.34` and not `12-34`.  How can this be accomplished?

```
#!/bin/sh

ip=$1  
echo $ip
if netstat | grep ssh | grep $ip;  then
        netstat | grep ssh | grep $ip
else
        echo 'No'
fi
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `grep` with the `-F` option:

From man grep:

```
 -F, --fixed-strings
         Interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings (i.e. force grep to
         behave as fgrep).
```

Your example:

```
grep -F "$ip"
```

Comment: You should quote `"$ip"`, or patterns containing spaces or glob characters result in interesting surprises.

Comment: @BenjaminW. you're absolutely right, I'm adding it as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` using regex to match strings.  `.` is a special character in regex, so it needs to be escaped.  There is a rather elegant way of doing this:

```
export escaped_ip_addr = $(echo $ip_addr | sed "s/\./\\\./g")
```

Which would make your final code:

```
#!/bin/sh

#test.sh

ip=$1
echo $ip

export escaped_ip = $(echo $ip | sed "s/\./\\\./g")
if netstat | grep ssh | grep $escaped_ip;  then
        netstat | grep ssh | grep $escaped_ip
else
        echo 'No'
fi
```

Comment: Did you try this? You can't assign with spaces around `=`.